# IntelliJ IDEA - omit default Java class header generation

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Every time when I use IDEA and create a Java class with normal "New Java class" menu option, it generates an ugly and useless Javadoc-style header before the class itself:

```
/**
 * Created by greycat on 18.03.14.
 */
```

I might rant a lot on why is it useless, for example:

1. I would have authorship & timestamps in my VCS anyway
2. It blatantly breaks any Javadoc documentation practices (for instance, using `@author` or `@since` tag)
3. It uses ugly, ambiguous, locale-specific date format

Is there a way to disable this behavior, i.e. just create normal, clean class template, without this header?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

After the class is generated you can click on the generated text and press alt-enter.
This shows you an option to edit the template.

Comment: Thanks for a great insight on using the omni-useful `Alt+Enter` combo ;)

Comment: I always tend to press alt-enter on everything to see what it does ;)

Answer (score 28):

The following is valid for IDEA 13.x.

Files -> Settings, under IDE Settings, select "File and code templates".

In the right panel, you will see several tabs: choose "Includes". There is a "File Header" entry: select this, modify and save.

Note that this header applies to *all* file types.

Note also that this is a separate setting from copyright notices, which you can set per project.

Answer (score 19):

### IntelliJ IDEA 15

#### Method 1

1. **File** > **Settings...** (or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>)

   [image: File > Settings...]
2. **Editor** > **File and Code Templates** > **Includes** > **File Header** > remove the comment from the right side

   [image: Remove comment]

#### Method 2

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> > type "File Header S" > choose "File Header" from "Settings" (the first line)

   [image: Action File Header S]
2. Remove the comment from the right side

Answer (score 3):

To change this template use File | Settings | File (and Code) Templates.

See also: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/file-and-code-templates.html